# Finding the difference between 2 dates and iterating an image based on the difference

Tags: php, mysql, image, date

Ive managed to loop through a table and get the difference in days between 2 dates adjacent to each other in the table.

Multiple entries have the same date, i have it now that when that date changes, it displays an image however i want it to display the image as many times as the difference in date

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Films_Info") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 $last_value = null;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

  if (!is_null($last_value)) {
  $a = new DateTime($row['FilmRelease']);
  echo "<p>".$row['FilmName']."</p>";
  $interval = $a->diff(new DateTime($last_value));
  //echo $interval->format('%d days');
  $i = 0;

}
$howManydays = $interval->days;

for ( $i; $howManydays; $i++) {
    echo "<img src=\"day.jpg\" />";
    $howManydays = 0;

}

  $last_value = $row['FilmRelease'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for ( $i = 0; $i < $howManydays; $i++)`  The second is a conditional statement telling when the loop should stop.

The first section in the for loop where it says `$i = 0` initialized the variable `$i` to 0 and then tests the condition `$i < $howManydays`.

Let's say `$howManydays` equals 1. That means 0 < 1, so the loop will perform.

At the end of the loop, the third section is called (`$i++`), so `$i` is incremented and now equals 1. The second section is called again to test conditions `$i < $howManydays` which is asking if 1<1 which it's not, so the loop will exit.

So if `$howManydays` is greater than 0, the loop should happen the integer amount that is in `$howManydays`.

You will want to remove `$howManydays = 0;` within the for loop, if you don't want it to only fire once.

The for loop

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < $howManydays; $i++){
  // ...
}
```

is somewhat equivalent to the while loop:

```
$i = 0;
while ( $i < $howManydays ){
  // ...
  $i++;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php for more information

In your code above, you should also check if interval was set. You should probably just do an if rather than a while, if only need one interval.

Comment: How would I go about doing it, in the while loop and not using a conditional statement?

Comment: Even regular statements are conditional statements, it's evaluated as either true or false and if it's false you break the loop. You can create a infinite loop and break within it if you want. I'm unsure exactly what you need.

Comment: I want to loop an image based on as many times as the day difference between the two dates. if there is no difference then the image won't display

Comment: @DIM3NSION I've updated the answer to what you changed to and gave an explanation. I hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

you could just do a simple division on the interval and print out the image that many times

```
$last_value_u   = $last_value->format('U');
$a_u            = $a->format('U');

$interval       = $a_u - $last_value_u;

$image_count    = intval($interval/86400);

for($i=0;$i<$image_count;$i++)
    echo "<p><img src=\"day.jpg\" /></p>";
```

### Update

An alternative option would be to loop through the interval:

```
for($i=$last_value_u;$i<$a_u;)
{
    if(intval(($a_u - $i)/86400) == X)
    {
        // run special code for specific day
    }
    else
    {
        // run code for every other day
    }
    $i+=86400;
}
```

Comment: updated my post with a close but not perfect working an example. anychance you could help me display multiple images depending on the difference in date. it only displays the one image even if there is 6 days diference

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but I updated my answer with what I think will help.  Also in your for loop the second statement in the clause is supposed to be a test (ie- `$i < $limit`) and you're setting that second statement on each loop by stating `$howManydays = 0;` this will cause an infinite loop